# How to save the state of a stateful tensorflow keras model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to write a new method to analyze the predictions of a time-series forecast. Therefore, I need to copy my learned model at every timestamp (of the prediction) or reset it to a previous point and feed it with different inputs.

I use:

- tensorflow.python.keras (tf version: 1.12)
- python 3.7

My Network:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(100, return_sequences=True, stateful=True, batch_size=batchSize, input_shape=(x, y)))
model.add(Dropout(dropout))
model.add(GRU(units, return_sequences=False, stateful=True))
model.add(Dropout(dropout))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="linear", kernel_constraint=min_max_norm(min_value=-10)))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='nadam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The only thing which is currently working is, to predict the previous steps from scratch:

```
for i in range(timestamps):
    for j, features in enumerate(featuresTable[i]):
        if i > 0:
            model.predict(np.reshape(featuresList[:i], (i, 1, featuresList.shape[1])),
                                              batch_size=self.batch_size)
        predict = model.predict(np.reshape(features, (1, 1, len(features))), batch_size=self.batch_size)
        model.reset_states()
```

where  `timestamps` is the number of timestamps, `featuresTable` is a table with the alternative features for each timestamp and `featuresList` are the normal features

What I want:

```
state = getState(model)
for i in range(timestamps):
    for j, features in enumerate(featuresTable[i]):
        predict = model.predict(np.reshape(features, (1, 1, len(features))), batch_size=self.batch_size)
        setState(model,state)
    model.predict(np.reshape(featuresList[i], (1, 1, featuresList.shape[1])), batch_size=self.batch_size)
    state = getState(model)
```

thank you in advance
~ Lifree